# Test Entity Framework Find Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to test the that the `GetSystem(int id)` method in `SystemService.cs` returns the correct value, but can't seem to figure out how to get everything to play well together. It seems that no matter what I do, `GetSystem()` always returns null. This is using Entity Framework 6. If I change the body of GetSystem to read `_context.Systems.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id = id)`, then everything works properly, but I'd really like to use `Find()`.

What is the proper way to test this? I'm using xUnit and Moq in this example. `SystemServiceTests.cs` shows the code that I'm currently using that isn't working.

**SystemService.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Services
{
  public class SystemService
  {
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public SystemService(MyContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    public Models.System GetSystem(int id)
    {
      return _context.Systems.Find(id);
    }
  }
}
```

**SystemServiceTests.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.Unit
{
  public class SystemServiceTests
  {
    [Fact]
    public void GetSystemReturnsFromContext()
    {
      var data = new List<Models.System> {
        new Models.System { Id = 1, Name = "test 1" },
        new Models.System { Id = 2, Name = "test 2" }
      }.AsQueryable();

      var mockContext = new Mock<MyContext>();

      var mockSet = new Mock<MockableDbSetWithIQueryable<Models.System>>();
      mockContext.Setup(c => c.Systems).Returns(mockSet.Object);

      mockSet.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
      mockSet.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
      mockSet.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
      mockSet.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

      var service = new SystemService(mockContext.Object);
      var system = service.GetSystem(1);

      Assert.NotNull(system); // This is always null
    }
  }
}
```

**MyContext.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
  public class MyContext : DbContext
  {
    public MyContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Models.System> Systems { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**System.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
  public class System
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**MockableDbSetWithIQueryable.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.Helpers
{
  public abstract class MockableDbSetWithIQueryable<T> : DbSet<T>, IQueryable
    where T : class
  {
    public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    public abstract Expression Expression { get; }
    public abstract Type ElementType { get; }
    public abstract IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
  }
}
```

PS. Some of the code for this, specifically `MockableDbSetWithIQueryable` was found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn314429

Comment: Can you not do `mockContext.Setup(c => c.Systems).Returns(data);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the *recommended* way to test everything using Entity Framework 6. The resource for this recommendation is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn314431.

In a nutshell, test classes need to be created for each bit that needs to be tested. What I ended up doing is the following:

**TestDbSet.cs**

```
public class TestDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    ObservableCollection<TEntity> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public TestDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public override TEntity Add(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Remove(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Attach(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
    }

    public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }

    public override ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _query.ElementType; }
    }

    Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _query.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _query.Provider; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**TestSystemDbSet.cs**

```
class TestSystemDbSet : TestDbSet<Models.System>
{
    public override Models.System Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var id = (int)keyValues.Single();
        return this.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }
}
```

**TestContext.cs**

```
public class TestContext: IContext
{
    public TestContext()
    {
        this.Systems = new TestSystemDbSet();
    }

    public DbSet<Models.System> Systems { get; set; }

    public int SaveChangesCount { get; private set; }
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.SaveChangesCount++;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**SystemServiceTests.cs**

```
public class SystemServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetSystemReturnsFromContext()
    {
        var context = new TestContext();
        context.Systems.Add(new Models.System { Id = 1, Name = "System 1" });
        context.Systems.Add(new Models.System { Id = 2, Name = "System 2" });
        context.Systems.Add(new Models.System { Id = 3, Name = "System 3" });

        var service = new SystemService(context);
        var system = service.GetSystem(2);

        Assert.NotNull(system);
        Assert.Equal(2, system.Id);
        Assert.Equal("System 2", system.Name);
    }
}
```

**SystemService.cs**

```
public class SystemService : ISystemService
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public SystemService(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Models.System AddSystem(Models.System system)
    {
        var s = _context.Systems.Add(system);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return s;
    }

    public Models.System GetSystem(int id)
    {
        return _context.Systems.Find(id);
    }
}
```

**ISystemService.cs**

```
public interface ISystemService
{
    Models.System AddSystem(Models.System system);
    Models.System GetSystem(int id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Find()` is returning `null` because that is the default value for `System`. The collection does not contain an item with id `id`.

`.Find()` is a method of `List`.

I suggest you use LINQ's `FirstOrDefault()`

The reason being, you can use lazy loading by returning an `IQueryable`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, but doesn't Find() query the local context first and only hit the database if it can't find anything?

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to directly instantiate a DbSet, since its constructor is marked protected.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. `Find()` just quiries the list in memory. I reccommend using `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: I could use `FirstOrDefalut()`, but I'd really like to use `Find()` in this case because of the efficiency it introduces by not querying the database if it doesn't have to. Is there any way to test when `Find()` is used?

Comment: `Find()` does not have this behaviour. `Find()` is from before LINQ. It's a method of `List`!

Comment: The issue isn't `LINQ` vs. something else, it's testing the framework (Entity Framework) ensure it's working properly. In this case, `Find()` is actually a member of DbSet, which implements `IDbSet<TEntity>`. I'm looking for a way to mock DbSet in such a way that `Find()` will work like it would in a production system. However, I'm not sure if that will be possible.

Comment: I see. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx You are not mocking your context correctly.